# where is the text printed by C printf

Tags: io, common-lisp, cffi

I happened encounter a trouble with calling C printf function from SBCL via cffi.  The problem is when I call printf function, I can't find the output text, just the return value of printf function show on the REPL. But when I quit SBCL, the output text appears on the terminal magically.

```
  $ sbcl
  * (ql:quickload :cffi)
  * (cffi:foreign-funcall "printf" :string "hello" :int)
  ;;=> 5
  * (quit)
  hello$
```

The last line, "hello$" means when quit from SBCL, the text "hello" appears on terminal and followed with the shell prompt "$".  So where does printf print the text "hello" to?

I tried `finish-output', `force-output' on *standard-output* but that does not work.

Comment: Typically looks like output is buffered and you need to tell C to empty the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that C's stdio library has its own buffering that has nothing to do with Lisp's. Flushing the output requires you to have a pointer to C's `FILE *stdout` variable. You can get this pointer like this:

```
 (cffi:defcvar ("stdout" stdout) :pointer)
```

Then, after using `printf`:

```
(cffi:foreign-funcall "fflush" :pointer stdout :int)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in SBCL 2.0.11 for MacOS.  I get the error message `Trying to access undefined foreign variable "stdout".`. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Write in `flush.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void flush() { 
    fflush(stdout); 
}
```

Then:
`gcc -fpic -shared flush.c -o flush.so`

Then in SLIME:

```
(cffi:load-foreign-library "./flush.so")
(cffi:foreign-funcall "puts" :string "Hello World" :int)
(cffi:foreign-funcall "flush")
```

But only print in `*inferior-lisp*`, even with `(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*...)`